# Instantiating and calling a specific method of the subclass from base class module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a scenario whereby I'd like to have a base class A (defined in a.py) with all of the generic logic accompanied by a single method `foo()` to be implemented by derived classes. That is, **a.py** would have

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A()"
    def foo(self):
        print "A.foo()"
```

and file **b.py**,

```
from a import A
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__();
        print "B()"
    def foo(self):
        print "B.foo()"
```

Now I can add

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    B().foo()
```

to b.py and run via `python b.py`, but I'd like to see if there's a way to avoid doing this in all the subclass modules. This way all I have to do is instruct the subclass developers to provide a sensible `foo()` (along with any extra setup in the overridden `__init__()`), without having to add the `if __name__ == "__main__"` bit as I want that bit to always call the `foo()` method on the object of the class being provided by the module.

My hunch is that this cannot be done in Python since it amounts to instantiating the subclass objects from within a.py, but I'd like to see if others can provide a concrete answer for me, or even better a way around.

Comment: neither A nor B has a method `run`.

Comment: who and when should `foo` be called? From a main program, and this main program should say, which subclass is initialized. And can call `foo`. So where is the problem?

Comment: @Daniel Meant `foo()`. Have updated the question. When a b.py script is run containing class B, I want the a.py file providing the base class A (and being `import`ed into b.py) to be able to instantiate the class B and run `foo()` on the object of type B.  Thinking more about it, I see that it probably cannot be done in a language-sanctioned way. My hope was that since methods, etc in Python are available through attribute dictionaries, perhaps someone had a way around it.